# Google Script Error - Trouble moving rows by dropdown and trouble deleting the old empty row that has moved

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hoping for some clarification. The below was my first attempt with scripts, I normally use basic Excel/Google formulas. I am sure my errors a caused by an over-complicated formula, I would appreciate the help!!

I keep track of my purchases by entering them into a Google Sheet called "OpenPOs" while I wait for the orders to arrive. Each order takes up one row and has eight columns of information... I want rows to move to a specific page of this Google sheet when selecting from a dropdown while keeping/transferring any formulas of that row's info intact.

1. I want lines from **OpenPOs** to move to the second sheet named **Received** once I select from the dropdown list 'received' and then delete the empty row that was moved from the OpenPos page.
2. I also require the lines to do the same thing from the **Received** page when I select the dropdown option 'invoiced', move to the **Invoiced** page and delete the empty row from the received page.
3. Any moved rows need to keep the formulas intact when moved to their new page.
4. Not in the formula below: But if someone could help me also make these lines move back to previous sheets if we later decide they were not actually received or invoiced that would be cool too.

With the below formula, I experienced the below issues:

- When selecting from the dropdown to move a row, sometimes deletes the old row that was moved along with a valid row below it that should remain on that page
- When selecting from the dropdown to move a row, sometimes the row disappears from the sheet without moving to my requested sheet being lost until I Ctrl-Alt-Z to reverse what was done.
- When selecting from the dropdown to move a row, no rows that move bring their formulas.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = e.source;
  var activatedSheetName = ss.getActiveSheet().getName();
  var activatedCell = ss.getActiveSelection();
  var activatedCellRow = activatedCell.getRow();
  var activatedCellColumn = activatedCell.getColumn();
  var activatedCellValue = activatedCell.getValue();
 
  var OpenPOs = ss.getSheetByName("OpenPOs"); // 1st source sheet 
  var Received = ss.getSheetByName("Received"); // 1st target sheet 

  var Received = ss.getSheetByName("Received"); // 2nd source sheet 
  var Invoiced = ss.getSheetByName("Invoiced"); // 2nd target sheet

 
  // if the value in column F is "Received", move the row to target sheet
  if (activatedSheetName == OpenPOs.getName() && activatedCellColumn == 6 && activatedCellValue == "Received") {
    // insert a new row at the second row of the target sheet
    Received.insertRows(2,1);
    // move the entire source row to the second row of target sheet
    var rangeToMove = OpenPOs.getRange(/*startRow*/ activatedCellRow, /*startColumn*/ 1, /*numRows*/ 1, /*numColumns*/ OpenPOs.getMaxColumns());
    rangeToMove.moveTo(Received.getRange("A2"));
    // delete row from source sheet
    OpenPOs.deleteRows(activatedCellRow,1);
  }
  // if the value in column F is "Invoiced", move the row to target sheet
  if (activatedSheetName == Received.getName() && activatedCellColumn == 6 && activatedCellValue == "Invoiced") {
    // insert a new row at the second row of the target sheet
    Invoiced.insertRows(2,1);
    // move the entire source row to the second row of target sheet
    var rangeToMove = Received.getRange(/*startRow*/ activatedCellRow, /*startColumn*/ 1, /*numRows*/ 1, /*numColumns*/ Received.getMaxColumns());
    rangeToMove.moveTo(Invoiced.getRange("A2"));
    // delete row from source sheet
    Received.deleteRows(activatedCellRow,1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problems that you are experiencing could be resolved by making use of [Event Ojects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events). The proposed answer, they provide the edited sheet, row and value.

---

```
function onEdit(e) {

  // Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)) // DEBUG

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var received = ss.getSheetByName("Received"); // 1st target sheet 
  var invoiced = ss.getSheetByName("Invoiced"); // 2nd target sheet

  // get specific Event Objects
  var editedValue = e.value
  var editedsheet = e.range.getSheet()
  var editedRow = e.range.rowStart

  // test for an entry on OpenPOs
  if (editedValue === "Received" && editedsheet.getName() === "OpenPOs" ){
    var targetLastRow = received.getLastRow()
    editedsheet.getRange(editedRow,1,1,5).moveTo(received.getRange(targetLastRow+1,1));
    editedsheet.deleteRow(editedRow);

  }
  // test for an entry on Received
  if (editedValue === "Invoiced" && editedsheet.getName() === "Received"){
    var targetLastRow = invoiced.getLastRow()
    editedsheet.getRange(editedRow,1,1,5).moveTo(invoiced.getRange(targetLastRow+1,1));
    editedsheet.deleteRow(editedRow);
  }
}
```

---

**Sample Data**

**OpenPOs - Before**

[image: opbefore]

**OpenPOs - After**

[image: POafter]

**Invoiced - after**

[image: invoiced after]